# geth v1.9.13 - web3.exceptions.BadFunctionCallOutput: Could not decode contract function call func return data b'' for output_types ['uint256']

Tags: go-ethereum, web3.py

For clearity I am using two different ubuntu machines as follows, please note that both machines are sync to my private black chain and working on the same smart-contract:

Contract call was working on `1.9.9` where it starts not to work on `1.9.13`.

=> **ubuntu-a** uses:

```
- web3==5.7.0`, Python `3.6.8`, OS: `linux` on `venv`
- geth Version: 1.9.9-stable

Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

---

=> **ubuntu-b** uses:

```
- On `web3==5.7.0`, Python `3.7.5` on `venv` I have also tried for Python `3.6.8`
- geth Version: 1.9.13-unstable

Ubuntu 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan
```

---

Following function call works using `web3py` on **ubuntu-a** which has (geth Version: 1.9.9-stable): but when I upgrade the geth version to geth Version: 1.9.13-unstable it starts not to work.

```
contract.functions.getReceivedStorageDeposit(b'97fc72c7b24e499b79cb9e2d42300ad1').call()
```

where the function has the following signature:

```
function getReceivedStorageDeposit(bytes32 sourceCodeHash)
    external
    view
    whenProviderRegistered returns (uint256)
```

---

On **ubuntu-b**, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alper/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 1432, in call_contract_function
    output_data = web3.codec.decode_abi(output_types, return_data)
  File "/home/alper/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eth_abi/codec.py", line 181, in decode_abi
    return decoder(stream)
  File "/home/alper/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 127, in __call__
    return self.decode(stream)
  File "/home/alper/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eth_utils/functional.py", line 45, in inner
    return callback(fn(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/alper/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 173, in decode
    yield decoder(stream)
  File "/home/alper/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 127, in __call__
    return self.decode(stream)
  File "/home/alper/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 198, in decode
    raw_data = self.read_data_from_stream(stream)
  File "/home/alper/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 308, in read_data_from_stream
    len(data),
eth_abi.exceptions.InsufficientDataBytes: Tried to read 32 bytes.  Only got 0 bytes

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "koo.py", line 5, in <module>
    eBlocBroker.functions.getReceivedStorageDeposit(b"").call()
  File "/home/alper/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 904, in call
    **self.kwargs
  File "/home/alper/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 1454, in call_contract_function
    raise BadFunctionCallOutput(msg) from e
web3.exceptions.BadFunctionCallOutput: Could not decode contract function call getReceivedStorageDeposit return data b'' for output_types ['uint256']
```

**[Q]** What may cause this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: I tried to comment on this question when you just posted it, but you deleted it before I managed to complete the comment and send it. Anyway, can you try to replace `b'97fc72c7b24e499b79cb9e2d42300ad1'` with `0x97fc72c7b24e499b79cb9e2d42300ad1` (an integer), and also with `'0x97fc72c7b24e499b79cb9e2d42300ad1'` (a string)? At least on web3.js, I know that the string option works, so perhaps web3.py dev-team has decided to align with "the parent".

Comment: Sorry I thought it was related to `web3py`'s version or Python. I tried both cases but I wanted to be sure. I have tried using `"0x..."` which also had the same error message.

Comment: It does sound related to web3.py version (at least it did in the original question, maybe I've missed some of your points in this one)... So I figured that they might have decided to align it with web3.js behavior, hence the error.

Comment: Its pretty difficult on my end to figure out what's wrong because the latest web3py works on ubuntu version 18.0 but does not work on the version 19.0. Its also diffuclt to downgrade ubuntu to debug it more. Could it also be related to `geth` version?

Comment: BTW, `97fc72c7b24e499b79cb9e2d42300ad1` is only 16 bytes, so why are you passing this piece of data to a function which expects 32 bytes? The `b` prefix indeed makes it into an array of 32 bytes, but the information contained in each one of them is at most 4-bit long. Is that really what you had in mind?

Comment: I obtain `97....d1` value as an output of `md5sum <file_path>` or `md5 <file_path>` on purpose. But `md5sum` should return 32 bytes, I didn't understand why it is 16 bytes.

Comment: Each hexadecimal digit is 4 bits. You have 32 such digits in your string, which means that this string represents 32 * 4 bits = 128 bits = 16 bytes.

Comment: For example, try `print(0x97fc72c7b24e499b79cb9e2d42300ad1.to_bytes(32,'big'))`. You see it adds 16 zeros at the beginning. BTW, you might actually wanna use this format rather than the preceding `b` (though for passing it to a contract, you would wanna use `'little'`, since the Solidity compiler is Little-Endian).

Comment: Ah found it its related to geth version! works on `1.9.9-stable` but does not on `1.9.13-unstable`! I will look into your advice on ` Little-Endian`

Comment: My main point is the fact that you're passing 128-bits of information to a function which takes 256-bits as input. And while it may be so that you're interested in passing only 128 bits of data (encapsulated in 256 bits, with the MSB half being all zeros), I believe that this is not your actual intention.

Comment: I think I get confused related to this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317276/md5-is-128-bits-but-why-is-it-32-characters) // but since its output is 128 bits  , half of it should be empty. My main intention was just to obtain the hash of a source-code, for that I was using `md5sum` algorithm, which actually generates 128 bits.

Comment: For hashing, why not use `keccak256`?

Comment: Linux seems like has `md5sum, sha1, sha256, sha384, sha512, crc32` algorithms. I can investigate `keccak256` 's alias for hashing folder/files. But most of the cloud-services stick with `md5sum` (like google-drive) so that's why it was my first starting point.

Comment: Web3.js has `Web3.utils.keccak256`. Why not use the equivalent function on Web3.py?

Comment: Can it calculate for files like a `.tar.gz` files?

Comment: You can pass any string to it.

Comment: How about using `SHA256` which as I understand generated 32-bytes?

Comment: Well, depends on what your overall purpose is. For example, if you're using `keccak256` on-chain (i.e., in one of your contracts) for authenticating an input hash, then you gotta use the exact same hash function off-chain (i.e., in your web3.py script). And I'm pretty sure that it won't work in that case because `sha256 != keccak256` AFAIK.

Comment: I have never used web3.py later than v4.9.2, but there you go - [keccak and keccak256 on web3.py v5](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#cryptographic-hashing).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105722/discussion-between-alper-and-goodvibration).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@karalabe (https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/20785#issuecomment-601590678)

> We've merged in a change to `eth_call` so that it will
>   not default to your first account if you don't specify any sender
>   (rather to 0x00). This was made to make the operations more
>   predictable in different environments.

---

I was calling as follows, where inside `call()` was empty:

```
self.eB.functions.func(source_code_hash).call()
```

adding `from:` option identifying the called addres is fixed the problem.

```
self.eB.functions.func(source_code_hash).call({"from": self.w3.toChecksumAddress("0x47b60037B89954eC7149132c606BA024fBb0f991")})
```